# php security for location header injection via $_GET

Tags: php, security

I've got this code on my page:

```
header("Location: $page");
```

$page is passed to the script as a GET variable, do I need any security? (if so what)

I was going to just use addslashes() but that would stuff up the URL...

Comment: I don't actually care if they can use it to get to a different page. I just want to be sure they can't do anything to the server, see my code etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I** could forward **your** users anywhere **I** like if I get them to click a link, which is definitely a big security flaw (Please login on www.yoursite.com?page=badsite.com). Now think of a scenario where badsite.com looks exactly like your site, except that it catches your user's credentials.

You're better off defining a `$urls` array in your code and passing only the index to an entry in that array, for example:

```
$urls = array(
    'pageName1' => '/link/to/page/number/1',
    'pageNumber2' => '/link/to/page/number/2',
    'fancyPageName3' => '/link/to/page/number/3',
);
# Now your URL can look like this:
# www.yoursite.com?page=pageName1
```

Comment: Do you mean define an array on URL's on that page and make sure the url that was passed to the script is in that array? I was originally going to do that but I realized that means I need to edit that page every time I add a URL.

Comment: Hintswen, if that's a problem, add a database table, give it a RESTful API for adding data (wouldn't worry about making a fancy method of editing or deleting stuff until you can be bothered) and make a bookmarklet which adds a URL to the list.

Comment: Why not just check if the url is on the same domain or not?

I didn't end up using a header redirect for my purpose but I just thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [code injection vulnerability](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection) by the book. The user can enter any value he wants and your script will obey without any complaints.

But one of the most important rules – if even not *the* most important rule – is:

> **Never trust the user data!**

So you should check what value has been passed and validate it. Even though a [header injection vulnerability was fixed with PHP 4.4.2 and 5.1.2 respectivly](http://docs.php.net/header), you can still enter any valid URI and the user who calls it would be redirected to it. Even such cryptic like `?page=%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%65%76%69%6c%2e%65%78%61%6d%70%6c%65%2e%63%6f%6d%2f` what’s URL encoded for `?page=http://evil.example.com/`.

Comment: lol just so you know, I don't really care what URL they get directed to, as long as they can't stuff up any code, view my code, edit files on my server.

Comment: No, `header` can only modify the HTTP header that’s being sent back to the client.

Comment: yeah but couldn't someone do something like this...
?page=");othercode

Comment: @Hintswen: No, that’s impossible. The string declaration cannot be left.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do. Just because you or I can't immediately think of a way to take advantage of that little bit of code doesn't mean a more clever person can't. What you want to do is make sure that the redirect is going to a page that you deem accessible. Even this simple validation could work:

```
$safe_pages = array('index.php', 'login.php', 'signup.php');
if (in_array($page, $safe_pages)) {
  header("Location: $page");
}
else {
  echo 'That page is not accessible.';
}
```

Comment: got it. that's actually what I originally had. but as I said to soulmerge I realized I would need to edit it every time I add a page/url

Answer (score 0):

Or, at the very least, define a whitelist of allowed URLs, and only forward the user if the URL they supplied is in the GET variable is in the list.