# How to get requested server name in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework

I uploaded my code files to example1.com and pointed another domain example2.com also to example1.com, both are showing the same content now.

Now I need to have a condition to make changes according to the domain that is being requested. How can I get it in PHP, I have seen the values in `$_SERVER` variable, but it couldn't help.

Comment: have you tried like this , $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?

Comment: @Manadh: Yes, have tried and both are showing example1.com only.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] this what shows ?

Comment: @Manadh: example1.com again!!

Comment: I used domain forwarding with masking actually, I think pointing and forwarding with masking are different things.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
$ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603225/get-the-page-a-user-viewed-before-current)

Comment: this is working, I found it in $_SERVER, but it is not that we shouldn't use HTTP_REFERER, as this can be manipulated?

Comment: this is problematic, if I go through both the site concurrently, it shows the weird behaviour as this gives the last page viewed.

Answer (score 0):

you can Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  --> 'localhost:8080'
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] --> 'localhost'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i have tried in this above domain name then domain name is displayed .

**Code:-**

```
<?php
echo "Server Name:".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."</br>";
echo "Domain Name:".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
?>
```

**Output:-**

```
  Server Name:  codepad
  Domain Name:  codepad.viper-7.com
```

Here **codepad** is a server name and 
**codepad.viper-7.com** is domain name.

Click here and check once.[Reference Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Lom4wH)

Comment: I believe Siamand Maroufi also wrote the same solution, didn't he?