# PHP tracking when links are clicked

Tags: php, redirect

Hello and thanks in advance for any suggestions you can lend.

What I am trying to accomplish: When a user clicks a link I want to add an auto-increment id, clicked URL and time stamp to the database and then send them to the URL links landing page.

The problem I am having: When the link is clicked the URL is not added to the database and the redirect also fails.

Here is the code I am working on:

**ad_click_tracking.php**

```
<?php


include ("admin/includes/connect.php");


mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());

//Collecting the destination URL from the clicked link
$redirect = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);

//Insert destination URL and time stamp into MySQL

$page_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ad_click_tracking (`url`, `date`) VALUES ('$redirect', now())") or die(mysql_error());

//Redirecting user to the clicked URL

header("Location: $redirect");

//Debugging to see if we collected the URL
echo "Redirect URL: $redirect";

?>
```

**header.php** (Contains the links to be tracked - the first link is internal the second link is external)

```
<a href="http://recyclingkansascity.com/ad_click_tracking.php?page="index.php" target="_blank"><img src="/images/header_banner/recycling_kansas_city_header.png" width="620px" height="340px" alt="Recycling Banner" title="Recycling Kansas City"></a></li>

<a href="http://recyclingkansascity.com/ad_click_tracking.php?page="http://paws4autism.org" target="_blank"><img src="/images/header_banner/funny_bunny_5k_autism_egg_hunt.png" width="620px" height="340px" alt="Paws 4 Autism" title="Paws 4 Autism Easter Event"></a></li>
```

When I click the internal or external link the browser displays the URL as recyclingkansascity.com/ad_click_tracking.php?page= and then when I check the database the id has been auto-incremented and the timestamp is inserted but the URL is null. For some reason the ($_GET['page']) seems to be failing to grab the page URL and I have not been able to figure out why as of yet. I read through relevant "similar questions" and was not able to find an answer.

Comment: what does var_dump($_GET) on ad_click_tracking.php give you ?

Comment: you might also want to change href="http://recyclingkansascity.com/ad_click_tracking.php?page="index.php" to href="http://recyclingkansascity.com/ad_click_tracking.php?page=index.php" and see if that helps (remove an extra " right before index.php)

Comment: You do know that it is extremly unsecure?

Just a small url manipulation and I can get anything:
http://recyclingkansascity.com/ad_click_tracking.php?page=passwd

Comment: Maximus2012: switching to var_dump didn't work. What did work was removing the extra " as you suggested. This totally fixed the first link to an internal page and now the link works as well as it adds to the database. This did not fix the external link though and it navigates to recyclingkansascity.com/ad_click_tracking.php?page=http://paws4autism.org when clicked and does not add the url to the database.

Comment: aqab0N: I had no idea it was unsecure so far I can't even get it working lol. Do you have any suggestion how I could make it more secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to create your links would be with PHP code such as this:

```
$url = 'http://paws4autism.org';
echo '<a href="http://recyclingkansascity.com/ad_click_tracking.php?page='
       . htmlspecialchars(urlencode($url)) . '" target="_blank">...</a>';
```

This will escape the url as a query string. It may or may not work without doing this, but this is the proper way to do it. For example, `http://paws4autism.org` would become `http%3A%2F%2Fpaws4autism.org`. If you are wondering about the double escaping, here it is broken down a bit:

```
$url = 'http://paws4autism.org';
// escape query string when constructing url:
// (this would be necessary even if you weren't rendering it as a link in html)
$href = 'http://recyclingkansascity.com/ad_click_tracking.php?page=' . urlencode($url);
// escape for html rendering:
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($href) . '">...</a>';
```

In ad_click_tracking.php, you ought to check whether `$_GET['page']` is set at all before you continue. Also, it doesn't make sense to be redirecting to the MySQL-escaped version of the page parameter. So, instead of this:

```
$redirect = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
// (...insert with $redirect...)
header("Location: $redirect");
```

I would do this:

```
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
  // this is a little bit more informative than just dying
  header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 400 Bad Request');
  die('No page specified');
}
$redirect = $_GET['page'];
$s_redirect = mysql_real_escape_string($redirect);
// (...insert with $s_redirect...)
header("Location: $redirect");
```

Lastly, the plain mysql library for PHP isn't really recommended for use. Mysqli (which uses nearly the same syntax) or PDO is preferred. See here: [MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php)

Oh, and as for the security of doing the HTTP redirect, see this page (I recommend reading through all the answers). The only real issue is related to phishing scams. You aren't serving a file that the user normally wouldn't have access to.
[php security for location header injection via $_GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897550/php-security-for-location-header-injection-via-get)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help I appreciate it!  narb: I implemented your suggestions. When landing on the page now it only displays No Page Specified. If I change the !isset to just isset then the page does load just fine but when I click the link it does not add to the database and the URL comes out as 'http://recyclingkansascity.com/ad_click_tracking.php?page=http%3A%2F%2Fpaws4autism.org' and does not push through to the actual landing page. For some reason it is retaining 'http://recyclingkansascity.com/ad_click_tracking.php?page=' and not just using the actual landing url?

Comment: @DisasterFaster That sounds you've got an extra quotation mark in there somewhere when you are creating the link. Maybe check the page source in your browser and see if there really are no extra quotes.

Comment: I just wanted to give a big thank you to everyone who took the time to help me out by providing help on this question. After making the changes that Narb suggested the code was just right but I still had an issue. The issue was the header redirect would only work on internal pages and would fail on external pages. Turns out the datacenter was blocking that for security reasons. After contacting them they white listed the script and now external redirects work perfectly and now all is just right.